# Select row with Multiple WHERE clauses in Mysql

Tags: mysql

i have an sql query like this:

```
SELECT
  u.id
  , u.name
  , id_number
  , c.name AS class
  , g.status
  , c.grade
  , end_year 
From
  users u 
  LEFT JOIN graduations g 
    on u.id = g.user_id 
  LEFT JOIN classes c 
    ON u.class_id = c.id 
WHERE
  u.role = 'student' 
  AND c.grade = 'x' 
  AND u.end_year IS NULL
```

everything work just fine. Until I want to add more condition, the user.end year can be also this year so I add this after the end of the query : `OR u.end_year = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`. But it doesn't work as I expected. it makes select all the user which has the **grade** other than **x**. so how's can I accomplish it with the grade must be just "x"?

Comment: `AND` instead of `OR`

Comment: @VincentRamdhanie no it's not working. it makes no user selected which suppose there is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  u.id
  , u.name
  , id_number
  , c.name AS class
  , g.status
  , c.grade
  , end_year 
From
  users u 
  LEFT JOIN graduations g 
    on u.id = g.user_id 
  LEFT JOIN classes c 
    ON u.class_id = c.id 
WHERE
  u.role = 'student' 
  AND c.grade = 'x' 
  AND ( 
    u.end_year IS NULL 
    OR u.end_year = YEAR (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
AND u.end_year IS NULL
```

to

```
AND (u.end_year IS NULL OR u.end_year = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
```

Right now your statement is returning all results that that satisfy this:

```
WHERE u.role= 'student' AND c.grade = 'x'
AND u.end_year IS NULL
```

or this:

```
u.end_year = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```